# How should I effectively clean the exterior of dirty plastic drum

Tags: water, cleaning, water-damage, plastic, rain

The drum in the picture got dirty during the house construction probably , some concrete might have got stained or the drum has been in the outside so due to sun or rain this could have happened.

But I'd like to clean and keep it good looking.

I tried cleaning this using plain water and soapy water still results are the same.

[image]

Comment: Squeeze the barrel in your arms or bang with a rubber mallet for the heavy stuff.  A stiff steel brush for the lighter stuff.  Paint for cement to make it look good again.

Comment: That has been outside in contact with construction elements for some time.  Elbow grease, scouring pads. Maybe some muriatic acid to get the concrete off . ( use proper eye and skin protection)...and yet still the drum may look used...because it was.

Comment: @crip659 - Thanks , I will try but do I have to try any specific type or variant of paint ? because the paint should not get peeled right ?

Comment: If the cement is bonded well to the plastic, maybe a paint for cement/concrete.  Plastic usually needs it's own paint type and both usually don't meet together.  The muriatic acid might work from the other comment, but is nasty to skin.

Comment: First try with water power sprayer, if it does not work, use Sand power sprayer

Comment: @RMDman - Thanks , I used elbow grease but nothing would change. ofcourse use the scouring pad. I will try **muriatic acid**.

Comment: @asinine - I neither have sand blaster nor have water pressure sprayer.It'd be the last thing I will try. Thanks for the suggestion anyways

Comment: I would rent a pressure washer.

Comment: I'd rent it if its possible